# How to add Ignite UI component in angular 5

Tags: angular, user-interface, ignite-ui

I have ignite UI controls and i have application (asp.net core 1.1) with angualar 5, so i have system.config.js file which is loading angularjs js file.
When i try to integrate ignite latest angular component in my project, it is not running.
1. install all npm package of ignite ui of angular.
2. try to enter the configuration in system.config.js file for loading the file.
3. import the component in app.module.ts file (i am not using webpack.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fum1b.png))

But i got the exception.

Comment: Share the code you have tried so far

Comment: This is a generic SystemJS exception. Please provide your code and the name of the package you're installing: igniteui-angular, or igniteui-angular-wrappers?